# Is it possible to find all files with a given inode? Efficiently?

Tags: unix, find, inode

It is possible to find all the paths to a file with a given inode, in general,  using `find`'s `-inum` option.  But this has awful performance for typical filesystems.  What options are there to improve performance?

Are there filesystems with special support for this task?  Are there `updatedb`-like utilities that index inodes?

The more general, the better the answer.

**Postscript** For more on requirements, see [What's a good solution for file-tagging in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/81563/whats-a-good-solution-for-file-tagging-in-linux/97245#97245)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey there is a similar question on SO, maybe that will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340263/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-all-the-file-with-the-same-inode

Comment: While link only answers may answer the question asked, it is better to include the important parts in the answer along side the link. Link-only answers tend to be prone to link decaying.

Answer (score 3):

```
debugfs -R "ncheck your_inode_num" /dev/sda
```

Comment: Do you know how `debugfs` builds up its map of inodes to paths?  (From what little I know about ext2fs, the inode table only tells you about the blocks used by and permissions/types of the inodes.)  Is it possible to use `debugfs` with a mounted partition?