# Windows tool to help tag a file by renaming it?

Tags: windows, file-management, tags

I'm looking for a tool like [Tabbles](http://tabbles.net/) which lets me tag a file. The problem with Tabbles, is that it's very platform dependent and it's not portable. If I tag a file with it and pass on the same file to someone else, they won't see the tags. To an extent, this is because of how Tabbles works. They keep track of the tags by maintaining a separate database.

What I need is a system that lets me associate the tag to the file and not in some separate database. For reference I've seen these answers,

[What's a good solution for file-tagging in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/81563/whats-a-good-solution-for-file-tagging-in-linux)

https://superuser.com/questions/212692/is-there-an-open-source-free-tagged-file-system-to-replace-hierachical-file-sys

My own searching beyond that has convinced me that there is no such thing as a universal tagging solution - at least with metadata. So, I've decided to just accept a solution which lets me rename the file to add/remove my own tags from it. The only problem is that I haven't found any user friendly system to do it. I define user friendly as something that lets me right click a file to edit it's 'tags'.

Any suggestions? Or am I supposed to make my own?

In a way, I guess I'm looking for a windows variant of this,

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/oyepa/

Comment: Have you checked out Tag Spaces? The UI needs a lot of work, but it does seem to do what you're asking for.